# Disable ad blocking in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, blocking, advertisements

It seems that Microsoft Edge has some kind of internal ad blocker, enabled by default. I am not using any kind of such plugins or solutions and yet on many sites (not on all of them) I see messages like this:

[image]

Which Microsoft Edge's setting controls this or how can I disable this feature?

I have tried to search Edge's settings for `ad`, `ads` and `block`, but all I have found was tracking prevention related settings. I have tried to lift *Settings → Privacy, search, and services → Tracking prevention* from *Balanced (recommended)* down to *Basic* or even disabling the whole feature, but it brings no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SmartScreen, an integrated ad filter that comes standard with Microsoft Edge, does indeed work. Take the following actions to deactivate it:

- Click on the three dots (...) in the top-right corner of Microsoft Edge after opening it.
- From the drop-down menu, choose "Settings."
- Scroll down and click "Site permissions" in the Settings tab.
- Select "Ads."
- Switch off the SmartScreen ad blocker by doing so.

By selecting the "Ads" option under the Site Permissions section, you can additionally manage how the ad blocker behaves on a per-site basis.
From there, you can decide whether to turn off the ad blocker completely or only allow advertisements on some websites or block ads on particular websites.

Keep in mind that this will just remove the SmartScreen ad blocker; it won't affect any additional ad filters you might have set up.